# reactjs version 18 to 16

Tags: reactjs, npm-install

hello i just downgrade my react version from 18 to 16 in order to install this package
react-messenger-customer-chat

apparently i get this error may i know which library i need to downgrade aside react and react-dom ?

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @testing-library/react@13.3.0
npm ERR! Found: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^16.14.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.14.0" from react-dom@16.14.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!     react-dom@"^16.14.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (react-scripts)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!   @testing-library/react@"^13.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.3.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^13.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Hello Friend\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full 
report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Hello Friend\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-02T11_35_17_557Z- 
debug-0.log
```

or any  similar packages to react-messenger-chat in order to run on ract version18 ?

note: i cant run npm i command after downgrade the react version

Comment: You'll have to downgrade other packages (in this case `@testing-library/react`) to a version with a compatible peer dependency version for React. Or you can run with the `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps` options as the error message suggests.

Comment: oh i seee that i was thinking earlier uhmm may i know the version of @testing-library/react  ? to compatible with react v16?

Comment: I'm not sure, you'll have to find the repo and look through the commit history until you find a compatible React version in the package.json file.

Comment: I set version ^12.0.0 for @testing-library/react , it worked for me